# Openshift origin - jenkins connection to external servers

Tags: jenkins, version-control, openshift-origin

I was wondering is it possible to build openshift origin the way where we can provide jenkins software + connection there to our version control server (includes mercurial, subversion, git). In a nutshell can we build those three from external source. I test tried openshift's own prebuilt vm image but it had only chance to build from localhost with git.

Anyone know is this setup even possible to build manually to a "gear"? Our goal would be to provide our workers a solid system where they could build their own jenkins environment and build all those three like in normal jenkins instance.

Update:

With external server I mean systems like github, gitlab, deveo, stash etc.